# Datatable's column definition conflict (client vs server-side)

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable which is populated via HTML DOM (the first page is automatically loaded and builds the HTML table) and the following pages are retrieved via AJAX.

When I initialize the data, i'm setting the column definitions data to the column index. When I fetch a new page, I cannot use the index, because the data comes from JSON objects and the attributes have proper names (not 0, 1, etc. ). So, there's a conflict in the column definitions for the initialization and for the next pages.

Can I create the datatable based on the DOM table withouth using the index of the coluns and using already the correct attribute ? I'm also not being able to set the data as a function (Requested unknown parameter {function}).

Comment: Can you not just populate the table from ajax initially? ie return the html values as though they were generated by your server side code.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your "return the html values". Anyways, instead of generating an HTML table with the first page, I am now generating a Javascript JSON variable (I didn't mentioned before that I'm using JSP/JSTL to build this). This way, I ensure that both times, the Datatable consumes JSON variables, and I can define the column's data as the object attributes and it works for both data modes.